# SwiftUI List subview not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, listview, swiftui

I'm trying to embed a view that contains a Header view and a List The header and list render in the original view, but the list completely disappears when I put it in the parent view. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I tried putting the header in the list, but then the entire view disappears.

Here is the code for the view that contains the list:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CityDetailCategoryView: View {
    let cityDetailViewModel: CityDetailViewModel
    let titles = ["Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5", "Category 6", "Category 7"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            SectionHeadingView(cityDetailViewModel: CityDetailViewModel, sectionTitle: "Categories")
            List {
                ForEach(titles, id: \.self) { title in
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CityDetailCategoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CityDetailCategoryView(cityDetailViewModel: CityDetailViewModel())
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

...and the code of the parent view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CityDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var cityDetailViewModel: CityDetailViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6, content: {
                    DetailHeaderImageView(cityDetailViewModel: CityDetailViewModel)
                    Group {
                        CityDetailTitleView(cityDetailViewModel: CityDetailViewModel)
                        CityDetailQuickFactsView(cityDetailViewModel: CityDetailViewModel)
                        CityDetailCategoryView(cityDetailViewModel: CityDetailViewModel)
                        CityDetailMiscellaneousView(cityDetailViewModel: CityDetailViewModel)
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Data provided by ****")
                                .font(.caption2)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 24)
                }) 
            }) 
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            .navigationBarTitle(cityDetailViewModel.cityDetail.name, displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        } 
    }
}

struct CityDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CityDetailView(cityDetailViewModel: CityDetailViewModel())
    }
}
```

image of the view containing the list:

[image: view containing the list]

image of the parent view:

[image: parent view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're embedding a scrolling view (`List`) inside another scrolling view (`ScrollView`), which is always going to have some inherent difficulties (and potentially strange UI/UX consequences with scrolling).

Because the `CityDetailCategoryView` doesn't have any inherent height besides its header (the rest can be collapsed into the `ScrollView`), it collapses to zero.

You can use `frame` to set a height for it, as shown in this simplified example (if you remove the `frame` call, it behaves the same as yours):

```
var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("item")
            }
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("item")
                }
            }.frame(height: 200) //<-- here
            Text("last item")
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, I think you'll still run the risk of funny scrolling behavior.

My suggestion would be to rearchitect your views so that you have *one* list or scrolling view for all of the content.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for that helpful explanation! I will play around with it.

Thanks again!!